# Using Javascript variables to store Ruby Output from <%= %>

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

`@tag` is a string.

Why does this work:

```
tag_tracker = "<%= @tag %>";
alert(tag_tracker);
```

But not this?

```
tag_tracker = <%= @tag %>; // Why is this not read as a string?
alert(tag_tracker);
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have JS inside of ERB files, you need to ensure that the javacript code that is generated is correct.

Let's assume that you have a string `"div"` stored in `@tag`

The first option:

```
tag_tracker = "<%= @tag %>";
alert(tag_tracker);
```

will generate a correct JS with `div` wrapped in quotes.:

```
tag_tracker = "div";
alert(tag_tracker);
```

The second one:

```
tag_tracker = <%= @tag %>;
alert(tag_tracker);
```

will generate JS without quotes around the `div`:

```
tag_tracker = div;
alert(tag_tracker);
```

and that is incorrect, because in this case `div` is interpreted as a variable, not as string.

Comment: For strings, using `<%= @tag.inspect %>` outputs `"div"` as well.. Although inspect will work for strings, integers and arrays, it will not work for Hashes. Although `.to_json` will in rails apps.